VB NET: Enviar correo desde una cuenta Outlook con Mailkit y oAuth2
Tengo un problema con el envío de correos desde mi aplicación de escritorio desarrollada en Visual Studio .NET, a ver si me podéis ayudar.
Estoy usando la librería Mailkit y hasta hace unos días funcionaba sin problema, pero parece ser que desde el 1 de Octubre Microsoft obliga a usar la autentificación oAuth2 en sus cuentas. Desde ese día, cada vez que intento enviar un correo me da el siguiente error:
"Client not authenticated to send mail. [MA3P292CA0012.ESPP292.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM"
Tras buscar información llegué a la conclusión que hay que enviar el correo usando oAuth2, y para eso hay que crear una cuenta en Azure, luego en el centro de administración Microsoft Entra crear un registro de aplicación y ahí obtengo un Id de Aplicación, una URI de redirección, etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth
Una vez hecho esto, y siguiendo algún código que encontré (por ejemplo https://gist.github.com/gscales/57216f70aef4b79ff2c0a0053152d5d0) intento enviar nuevamente pero ahora tengo el siguiente error:
"One of two conditions was encountered: 1. The Prompt.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not be honored, because user interaction was required. 2. An error occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the HTTP authentication flow from completing in a short enough time frame. "
El código que tengo es este:
    Dim From As String = "micuenta@outlook.com"
    Dim To_ As String = "destinatario@destinatario.com"
    Dim SMTPServer As String = "smtp.office365.com"
    Dim SMTPPort As Integer = 587

    Dim ClientId As String = "598d4225-c63a-4d28-9afb-db0cb064d8AA"
    Dim UserName As String = "micuenta@outlook.com"
    Dim redirectUri As String = "msal598d4225-c63a-4d28-9afb-db0cb064d8AA://auth"
    Dim scopes = New String() {"https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send"}

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim pcaConfig = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId).WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
    pcaConfig.WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    Dim TokenResult = Await pcaConfig.Build().AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.Never).WithLoginHint(UserName).ExecuteAsync()

    Dim message As New MimeMessage()
    message.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(From))
    message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(To_))
    message.Subject = "Asunto"
    message.Body = New TextPart("plain") With {.Text = "Mensaje del email"}

    Using client As New SmtpClient()
        client.Connect(SMTPServer, SMTPPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
        Dim oauth2 As New SaslMechanismOAuth2(UserName, TokenResult.AccessToken)
        client.Authenticate(oauth2)

        Await client.SendAsync(message)
        client.Disconnect(True)
    End Using

pero me da error en la línea
Dim TokenResult = Await pcaConfig.Build().AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.Never).WithLoginHint(UserName).ExecuteAsync()

¿alguien sabe cúal es el problema? ¿estoy siguiendo los pasos correctos? Porque ni siguiera tengo claro que esta sea la manera correcta.
Las variables "ClientID" y "redirectURI" creo que las tengo bien, las puedo ver en el panel de Azure. Pero no tengo claro que los valores de "UserName" y "scopes" sean los correctos. ¿de dónde los saco?
Muchas gracias por adelantado!
EDITO:
Siguiendo los pasos que me indicó LPZadkiel soy capaz de obtener un token, pero ahora me da otro error en la línea que hace el envío (a pesar que le mando ese token que previamente obtengo):
Await client.SendAsync(message)
el mesaje es "535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MR2P264CA0040.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-10-25T12:12:48.388Z 08DCF47FC7BEC86E]"
¿cual puede ser el problema ahora?

No veo que estes usando MSAL.NET que es lo que deberías hacer, Microsoft esta migrando la autenticación para que se haga con Microsoft Graph API y para ello tienes que usar la libreria MSAL.NET. Ahora el error que te aparece dice que no estas interactuando en la autenticación, te debiese levantar una ventana para que te conectes y aceptes la autorización. Si vas a tu registro de aplicación en microsoft selecciona "Quickstart" > "Mobile and desktop application" > "Windows desktop" te explica como debes hacerlo e incluso te da un projecto ejemplo de como se hace, te recomiendo seguir esos pasos

Buenas LPZadkiel. Gracias por el aporte, me permitió avanzar y ya consigo generar el token. Pero me sigue dando error al enviar, a pesar de usar ese token. Edité la pregunta para explicar en qué punto estoy ahora. A ver si me puedes echar un cable! no me puedo creer que sea tan complicado enviar un correo
